# Error on installing depot_tools for Chromium

Tags: installation

I was trying to install depot_tools on Ubuntu 10.04 as instructed by http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools. So I typed

> svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools

and the result is

> svn: REPORT of '/svn/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://src.chromium.org)

What should I do? I want to install depot_tools!

Answer (score 0):

svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools

Worked for me ..

It was rather strange, since 10 minutes ago I had a similar issue